# How can I call in Swift 3 the method prepare after the user's input has four characters?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I have the following methods:

```
@IBAction func postcodeTextfieldDidChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {

        if (postcodeTextField.text?.characters.count == 4) {
            self.postcode = postcodeTextField.text
            postcodeHas4Chars = true
        } else {
            postcodeHas4Chars = false
        }
    }
```

And the prepare-method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "CoffeeShopListWithPostcode" {
            if (postcodeHas4Chars == true) {
                if let list = segue.destination as? CoffeeShopListVC {
                    list.postcode = postcode
                } else {
                    print("Data NOT Passed!")
                }
            }
        } else { print("Id doesnt match with Storyboard segue Id")
        }
    }
```

The code works and I can send the postcode to the next ViewController, but how can I change the code to automatically call the method after the fourth input?
At the moment, the user must manually exit the input so that it can be executed.

Comment: So you want the segue to be automatically performed when the user enters the fourth character?

Comment: Yes that is correct. After typing the last character The app should automatically send the content to the next view. At the moment he has to leave the keyboard input before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time the text field's text change, check if the text is 4 characters. If it is, call `performSegue(withIdentifier, sender:)`. Simple:

```
@IBAction func postcodeTextfieldDidChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {

    if (postcodeTextField.text?.characters.count == 4) {
        self.postcode = postcodeTextField.text
        postcodeHas4Chars = true
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CoffeeShopListWithPostcode", sender: self)
    } else {
        postcodeHas4Chars = false
    }
}
```

Also, remember that you connect to the `editingChanged` event instead of the `valueChanged event`.

Comment: Thanks, but this method does not send the postcode (textinput) to the next view.

Comment: @Severin all you need to do is add the `performSegue` line. Did you delete anything?

Comment: Ah I made a mistake, the screen was always executed twice. Thanks Sweeper. By the way I have found another solution that works. after self.postcode = postcodeTextField.text I execute the postcodeTextField.endEditing(true) and this close the keyboard, which means that the seque will be execute.